# How can i extract the encoded part of multi-modal autoencoder and convert the .h5 model to a numpy array?

Tags: numpy, model, autoencoder, h5py, encoder

I am making a deep multimodal autoencoder model which takes two inputs and produces a two outputs (which are the reconstructed inputs). The two inputs are with shape of (1000, 50) and (1000,60) respectively and the model has 3 hidden layers and aim to concatenate the two latent layer of input1 and input2.

I would like to extract the encoded part of my model and save the data as a numpy array.

here is the complete code of the model :

```
input_X = Input(shape=(X[0].shape))

dense_X = Dense(40,activation='relu')(input_X)

dense1_X = Dense(20,activation='relu')(dense_X)

latent_X= Dense(2,activation='relu')(dense1_X)

input_X1 = Input(shape=(X1[0].shape))

dense_X1 = Dense(40,activation='relu')(input_X1)

dense1_X1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(dense_X1)

latent_X1= Dense(2,activation='relu')(dense1_X1)

Concat_X_X1 = concatenate([latent_X, latent_X1])

decoding_X = Dense(20,activation='relu')(Concat_X_X1)

decoding1_X = Dense(40,activation='relu')(decoding_X)

output_X = Dense(X[0].shape[0],activation='sigmoid')(decoding1_X)

decoding_X1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(Concat_X_X1)

decoding1_X1 = Dense(40,activation='relu')(decoding_X1)

output_X1 = Dense(X1[0].shape[0],activation='sigmoid')(decoding1_X1)

multi_modal_autoencoder = Model([input_X, input_X1], [output_X, output_X1], name='multi_modal_autoencoder')

encoder = Model([input_X, input_X1], Concat_X_X1)

encoder.save('encoder.h5')

multi_modal_autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss='mse')

model = multi_modal_autoencoder.fit([X,X1], [X, X1], epochs=70, batch_size=150)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `h5py` package you can get into your `.h5` file and extract exactly what you want:

```
f = h5py.File('encoder.h5', 'r')
keys = list(f.keys())
values = f.get('some_key')
```

You can hierarchically use `.get` many times to go deeper into your `.h5` file to extract what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response but what i meant by my question is to get as a result the following : assume we have 2 matrices and the encoded part aim to concatenate their features, so i need to get the result of the encoded part i.e for example (1000, 4) which 4 corresponds to the 2 features extracted from X and the 2 features extracted from X1

Comment: I tried your recommandation and it gives me model_weights as keys. And ````<HDF5 group "/model_weights" (9 members)>```` as value. the 9 members are ````array(['concatenate_1', 'dense_1', 'dense_2', 'dense_3', 'dense_4',
       'dense_5', 'dense_6', 'input_1', 'input_2'], dtype='<U13')````  . In my case i would like to extract the value of concatenate_1

Comment: So it is a different problem thou, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Excuse me for the bad explanation of the question

Comment: @Andrea, based on your second comment, `/model_weights` is a Group that has 9 datasets. Code to get `concatenate_1` is `f['/model_weights/concatenate_1']`. This returns a h5py object that behaves like a NumPy array. If you need an array, use: `f['/model_weights/concatenate_1'][:]` -- note `[:]` at the end.

Comment: Thank you @kcw78 for your response. Actually, i tried your suggestion but it returns the following error ````AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'encode' ```` Can you help me to resolve it please?

Comment: I am trying to deduce the `encoder.h5` schema from your output. This clearly indicates `/model_weights` is a Group: `<HDF5 group "/model_weights" (9 members)>`. Group members can be Groups or Datasets. I (incorrectly) assumed the next output were datasets. How did you get this output: `array(['concatenate_1', ... , dtype='<U13')`? What do you get when you use this: `print (f['/model_weights/concatenate_1'])`? If you get `<HDF5 dataset ...  >`, then try this: `print (f['/model_weights/concatenate_1'].dtype)`

Comment: When trying ````print (f['/model_weights/concatenate_1'])```` i got ````<HDF5 group "/model_weights/concatenate_1" (0 members)>````